# How to ignore Swagger request fields using Spring OpenAPI 3.0?

Tags: spring, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

We have the following *Token* schema while scmOrg is defined as a foreign key.

```
{
  id        integer($int64)
  scmOrg    ScmOrg{...}
  type      string
  rawToken  string
}
```

When opening the Swagger console, it builds the example input like this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "scmOrg": {
    "id": 0,
    "scm": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "baseUrl": "string",
      "clientId": "string",
      "clientSecret": "string"
    },
    "name": "string",
    "team": "string"
  },
  "type": "string",
  "rawToken": "string"
}
```

A new token can be added only for an existing *scmOrg* entity, so what I really want it to be is something more strait forward like this:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "scmOrg": {
    "id": 0
  },
  "type": "string",
  "rawToken": "string"
}
```

Is it possible with Swagger?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to achieve this. In fact you can edit your models to set `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)`. But, I am against doing so and in addition whatever you do on the model will be overwritten next time it is regenerated. Check this link, it is a bit old but it seems that the guys behind swagger don't seem to have this in their roadmap. https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/How-to-hide-Model-Information/m-p/183188#M347